# Starting Updates through AppCenter but no installation follows

Tags: updates, appcenter, shell

Already tryed the shell with 'sudo apt-get update' . It shows:

```
...
OK:1 http://graphics.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
OK:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                        
... and so on: OK
...
```

But still two updates are in line in the Appcenter. One of it is "Betriebssystem".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Startet my Laptop this Mondaymorning and found, that everything is ok. hm. But I don't know why ^^